# Sub div get pushed down in a main div

Tags: html, css

i am currently working on a contact page. Basically, i want to create a main container. Inside the main container contains a sub container which will be floating right. But whenever i tried to include some text, the sub container get "pushed down". Why is that so and how can i resolve it?

```css
.contact-container-main {
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: #808080;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.contact-container-main h2 {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #FF0000;
}
.contact-container-main p {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.contact-container-sub {
  width: 250px;
  height: 580px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-container-main">
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi comod sed dolor sit amet consect adipiscing elit
  </p>

  <div class="contact-container-sub">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing float:right on the sub-container you can add position:absolute; with top and right positions also a position:relative to the .contact-container-main.

```
.contact-container-main {
        width: 900px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #808080;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }
   .contact-container-sub {
       width: 250px;
       height: 580px;
       position: absolute;
       margin: 10px;
       background-color: #000000;
       right: 0;
       top: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a container for the text also with a float left

```
<div class="contact-container-main">
   <div class="contact-container-text">
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi comod sed dolor sit amet consect adipiscing elit
  </p>
</div>

  <div class="contact-container-sub">

  </div>
</div>
```